# Java Interfaces/Callbacks for Using 1 of 2 Possible Methods

Tags: java, methods, interface, callback

I have read up on Java Interfaces (callbacks) because I was told by a professor I should use callbacks in one of my programs. In my code, there are two Mathematical functions I can 'pick' from. Instead of making a method activate() and changing the code inside (from one function to the other) when I want to change functions, he said I should use callbacks. However, from what I've read about callbacks, I'm not sure how this would be useful.

**EDIT**: added my code

```
public interface 

    //the Interface
    Activation {
    double activate(Object anObject);
     }

    //one of the methods
    public void sigmoid(double x)
    {
        1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    }

       //other method
      public void htan(final double[] x, final int start,
      final int size) {

      for (int i = start; i < start + size; i++) {
        x[i] = Math.tanh(x[i]);
      }
    }

    public double derivativeFunction(final double x) {
      return (1.0 - x * x);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your relevant code?

Comment: that code should not compile since you may not have implementations in an interface

Comment: Right, I'm not trying to compile the code above, but show an example of what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use interfaces something like this would work.
I have a `MathFunc` interface that has a `calc` method.
In the program I have a `MathFunc` for mutliplication and one for addition.
With the method `chooseFunc` you can choose one of both and with `doCalc` the current chosen `MathFunc` will do the calculation.

```
public interface MathFunc {

   int calc(int a, int b);

}
```

and you can use it like that:

```
public class Program {

   private MathFunc mult = new MathFunc() {
       public int calc(int a, int b) {
           return a*b;
       }
   };

   private MathFunc add = new MathFunc() {
       public int calc(int a, int b) {
            return a+b;
       }
   };

   private MathFunc current = null;

   // Here you choose the function
   // It doesnt matter in which way you choose the function.
   public void chooseFunc(String func) {
       if ("mult".equals(func)) 
         current = mult;
       if ("add".equals(func))
         current = add;
   }

   // here you calculate with the chosen function
   public int doCalc(int a, int b) {
       if (current != null)
          return current.calc(a, b);
       return 0;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Program program = new Program();
       program.chooseFunc("mult");
       System.out.println(program.doCalc(3, 3)); // prints 9
       program.chooseFunc("add");
       System.out.println(program.doCalc(3, 3)); // prints 6
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. The If statements negate a bit of what I thought the usefulness of callbacks was, but its still good code. I ended up doing something very similar though. However, in my program method I passed an object type and a number and just used the number as a parameter to a method on the object passed.

Comment: It was just an example to show how you can use interfaces to switch between different functions ^^